# Stream audio from any app on phone to receiver

Tags: audio, streaming

I have an HTC One m7 phone and a [Marantz NR1604](http://us.marantz.com/us/Products/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?CatId=avreceivers&ProductId=NR1604) receiver (with a nice set of speakers).
Both are connected to my home WIFI network.

How do I stream audio from *any* app on the phone to the receiver over the WIFI network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPosed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/) and [BubbleUPnP's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=de) [Audio Cast Feature](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/10/bubbleupnp-update-allows-root-users-to-stream-audio-from-most-apps-to-any-upnp-or-dlna-device/).